# How to read letter by letter in textfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, checksum, verify

I want to verify a Singapore NRIC using javascript,
the formula is

1) Take for example I want to test the NRIC number S1234567. The first digit you multiply by 2, second multiply by 7, third by 6, fourth by 5, fifth by 4, sixth by 3, seventh by 2. Then you add the totals together. So,1×2+2×7+3×6+4×5+5×4+6×3+7×2=106.

2) If the first letter of the NRIC starts with T or G, add 4 to the total.

3) Then you divide the number by 11 and get the remainder. 106/11=9r7

4) You can get the alphabet depending on the IC type (the first letter in the IC) using the code below:
If the IC starts with S or T: 0=J, 1=Z, 2=I, 3=H, 4=G, 5=F, 6=E, 7=D, 8=C, 9=B, 10=A
If the IC starts with F or G: 0=X, 1=W, 2=U, 3=T, 4=R, 5=Q, 6=P, 7=N, 8=M, 9=L, 10=K

How can I read every single number to do the formula?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
string.charAt(charpos)
```

Should do the trick.

Alternatively,

```
string.substr(charpos,1)
```

You could also do

```
string[charpos]
```

but the first two above are recommended. This will return `undefined` if the string is empty, whereas the other alternatives will all return the null string.

Another idea is

```
string.split("")[charpos]
```

Finally, there is

```
string.slice(charpos,1)
```

Since you want a single character at a time I'd recommend `charAt`.

Comment: How to define each number into variable?

Comment: I was actually learning C#
for C# i can actually do the split into a array 
so like

var nric=(S9221434C);
String[] number=nric.split("");
string letter=number[0];
string one=number[1];
.........


am i suppose to do something like this?

Comment: @user1509555, by "define each number into variable" I guess you mean assign each digit to a variable; for that, or course, you can use the JavaScript assignment statement, such as `var d1=nric.charAt(1), d2=nric.charAt(2);` You can then do the multiplication and addition using standard JavaScript arithmetic expressions such as `var result=d1*2+d2*7;` etc. Although the result of all the expressions above, and therefore also the values of variables `d1` etc., will be strings, when you multiply them by 2 or 7 they will be coerced to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are arrays so you can assign variables to the letters assuming you know the string has a fixed length, which it appears so, and then create a function to evaluate the characters and do the correct thing:

```
var nric = 'S1234567'
var chars = {
  letter: nric[0],
  one: nric[1],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i have not learn java script before, so i have some problem with the syntax, can i know what's is the equal, plus and divide operate. Thanks!

Comment: function checkNRIC(Nric)
{
 var nric=(Nric);
 var chars={
  letter: nric[0],
  one: nric[1],
  two: nric[2],
  three: nric[3],
  four: nric[4],
  five:nric[5],
  six:nric[6],
     seven:nirc[7],
  eight:nric[8]
 }
  
  
 if(letter=S)
 {
  window.alert ("correct");
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  window.alert("wrong");
  return false;
 }
  
}

This is what i do, i try to type a S but i nv pop up any message box, is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @elclanrs answer:

```
var nric = 'S1234567'
var numVal = 0;     for(var i = 1, bound = nric.length; i < bound; i++){
      numVal +=  parseInt(nric[i]);
    }
if(nric[0] === 'S' && numVal === 28){
    alert('ok');
}else{
    alert('wrong');
}
```

should more or less do the trick. 
I trust, You can do the multiplying yourself  :-)

Comment: Thanks! Will try to do it!(Y)